# will R TinyTeX installation interfere with other LaTeX installations on my computer

Tags: r, latex, rstudio, r-markdown, tinytex

On my Windows computers I typically install MiKTeX, and on my Linux computers I typically install TeX Live. I write to R Markdown a lot and it is recommended I install the package called TinyTeX via `install.packages("tinytex")` then `tinytex::install_tinytex()` in the R Studio IDE.

Will this TinyTeX installation interfere with said installations of MikTeX and TeX Live and all associated programs (eg TeXstudio)? I don't want TinyTeX to break everything else on my computers associated with LaTeX. My Windows computers play well with MiKTeX and my Linux computers play well with TeX Live.

Comment: The R package tinytex can use a installed MikTeX or TeXLive. So while I think there will be no interference, it is unnecessary to install TinyTeX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I recommend that you uninstall your existing LaTeX distribution.

~ [Yihui Xie](https://yihui.name/tinytex/) in TinyTeX

I uninstalled MiKTeX when installing tinytex and haven't looked back, but I have co-workers who have tinytex and MiKTeX and have not experienced issues.